# Which value does e take here?

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have the following piece of code (note: this is to help me understand the concept so it is an example code not something I intend to run)

```
List ml; //my_list
Element *e;
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
{
    for(e=ml->first;e;e=e->next)
    #pragma omp task 
    process(e);//random function
}
```

It was mentioned that e will always have the same value, I am trying to think why is that and what the value will be.

My try/reasoning:

The value of e is changing inside `pragma omp single`, these changes don't get carried out inside task (If I am not mistaken no value of the single region get carried to inside the task unless I use something like `firstprivate(e)`, moreover, the value it will take will be random since we didn't initialize e to any variable outside the single and parallel omp region and that what will e take as a value, if we had initialized outside to a value x for example then e will always be x

Any help correcting or verifying my reasoning would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have added some comments to your example to hopefully make the behavior a bit clearer.

```
List ml; //my_list
Element *e;

#pragma omp parallel  // e is shared for the parallel region
#pragma omp single
{
   for(e=ml->first;e;e=e->next)
     #pragma omp task  // since e is shared, all tasks will see the "same" e
     process(e);
}
```

What happens is this (indicated by the comments above): you're declaring `e` outside of the scope of the `parallel` constructs.  As per the OpenMP specification, the variable will be shared across all the threads executing.  The `single` constructs then restricts execution to any one thread of the team (`e` is still shared across all the threads, see https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu113.html#x148-1600002.21.1).

When the picked thread encounters the `task` construct, the OpenMP specification mandates that the created task from the `task` inherits the sharing attributes of the `e` variable (shared), so all created tasks will see the same variable and the picked thread may overwrite the `e` variable while it executes the `for` loop.

That's where the `firstprivate(e)` comes in:

```
List ml; //my_list
Element *e;

#pragma omp parallel  // e is shared for the parallel region
#pragma omp single
{
  for(e=ml->first;e;e=e->next)
  #pragma omp task firstprivate(e) // task now receives a private "copy" of e
    process(e);
}
```

Here, the create tasks will have a private copy of `e` that is initialized with the current value of `e` as the picked thread progresses through the `for` loop.

Another way to fix this would be this:

```
List ml; //my_list

#pragma omp parallel  
#pragma omp single
{
  Element *e;   // e is thread-private inside the parallel region
  for(e=ml->first;e;e=e->next)
  #pragma omp task // task now receives a private "copy" of e w/o firstprivate
    process(e);
}
```

Since in this example, the OpenMP specification mandates that the variable should be treated as if you specified `firstprivate(e)` (see https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.1/openmpsu113.html#x148-1610002.21.1.1).

Comment: to be clear, any modifications done to e won't be "visible" to task as it will only take the global variable initialization?

Comment: Depend on how you make that change. If you use `firstprivate(e)` (or move the definition of `e` in to the `parallel` construct) the task will get a copy that is disconnected from the shared `e`, which can then independently, but will not change the copy of `e` in the task.

Comment: In your original code `e` will be overwritten with each iteration of the `for` loop and all previously created tasks will see the changes.